# OpenModelica external function explicit mapping warning

Tags: c, openmodelica

I can't find out how to properly remove the following warning in my OpenModelica project:

```
[1] 18:05:18 Translation Warning
[MyModel: 3:1-11:25]: An external declaration with a single output without explicit mapping is defined as having the output as the lhs, but language C does not support this for array variables. OpenModelica will put the output as an input (as is done when there is more than 1 output), but this is not according to the Modelica Specification. Use an explicit mapping instead of the implicit one to suppress this warning.
```

which appears when *Checking* my model (from inside OMEdit) which has the following function declaration as part of a package

```
within MyPackage;

impure function MyExternalFunction "My External Function"
input Real input1 "Input 1";
input Real input2 "Input 2";
input Real input3 "Input 3";
output Real result[2] "result1, result2";
external "C"  annotation(
    IncludeDirectory = "modelica://MyPackage/",
    Include = "#include \"my_code.c\"");
end MyExternalFunction;
```

where the actual C code looks something like this

```
void MyExternalFunction(double input1, double input2, double input3, double* result, size_t n) {
    result[0] = 1.2;  // result 1
    result[1] = 3.4;  // result 2
    n = 2;
}
```

I have read the external functions chapter in the OpenModelica specification to no avail.

The code compiles and returns values correctly as wanted.

How should I modify the code above to remove the warning?

Comment: This is actually an implicit mapping. You can go for explicit mapping via external "C" MyExternalFunction(input1, input2, input3, result, size(1, result)) annotation ... and this should get rid of the warning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adrian Pop, but sadly I'm too inexperienced to piece together what I need to do from that information alone. Should I put that line just above "IncludeDirectory" above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this I guess:

```
within MyPackage;

impure function MyExternalFunction "My External Function"
input Real input1 "Input 1";
input Real input2 "Input 2";
input Real input3 "Input 3";
output Real result[2] "result1, result2";
external "C" 
  MyExternalFunction(input1, input2, input3, result, size(1, result))
annotation(
    IncludeDirectory = "modelica://MyPackage/",
    Include = "#include \"my_code.c\"");
end MyExternalFunction;
```